# jquery set previous inputs to 0

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a checkbox at the end of 5 inputs and one dropdown. I am trying through jquery to set all the inputs and the dropdown before the checkbox to 0.

There will be many employees listed so it has to be only the ones before the checkbox.

My feeble attempt at the jquery. I have the .on as sometimes it will be called through ajax

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(document).on('click', '.fasCheck', function(){

    if ($(this).attr("checked") == "checked"){
        $(this).prev().parent().prev(".payWeek").next('input').prop('checked', true);;
    } else {

    }
    });     

});
```

The html:

```
<div class="returns" id="employee">
<h3>David Wilson</h3>
<div class="payWeek">
        <label for="MonthlyReturn0PayWeek1">Pay Week1</label>
        <input type="number" id="MonthlyReturn0PayWeek1" value="" maxlength="12" step="any" name="data[MonthlyReturn][0][pay_week1]">
    </div>
   <div class="payWeek">
        <label for="MonthlyReturn0PayWeek2">Pay Week2</label>
        <input type="number" id="MonthlyReturn0PayWeek2" value="" maxlength="12" step="any" name="data[MonthlyReturn][0][pay_week2]">
   </div>
   <div class="payWeek">
        <label for="MonthlyReturn0PayWeek3">Pay Week3</label>
        <input type="number" id="MonthlyReturn0PayWeek3" value="" maxlength="12" step="any" name="data[MonthlyReturn][0][pay_week3]">
   </div>
   <div class="payWeek">
        <label for="MonthlyReturn0PayWeek4">Pay Week4</label>
        <input type="number" id="MonthlyReturn0PayWeek4" value="" maxlength="12" step="any" name="data[MonthlyReturn][0][pay_week4]">
    </div>
    <div class="payWeek">
         <label for="MonthlyReturn0PayWeek5">Pay Week5</label>
         <input type="number" id="MonthlyReturn0PayWeek5" value="" maxlength="12" step="any" name="data[MonthlyReturn][0][pay_week5]">
     </div>
     <div class="payWeek">
          <label for="MonthlyReturn0PayWeeks">Pay Weeks</label>
          <select id="MonthlyReturn0PayWeeks" name="data[MonthlyReturn][0][pay_weeks]">
                <option value="0">0</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option selected="selected" value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
           </select>
      </div>                        
      <div class="payWeek">
           <label for="FAS">FAS</label>
           <input type="checkbox" class="fasCheck" name="FAS">
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You say that there will be more than one `#employee` -- I'd personally remove the `id` attribute from this div as it will result in many `#employee` divs, which is bad practice.  This is better suited for a class attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `$(this).attr("checked") == "checked"` won't work, you already know to use `.prop()`. Or just use `this.cecked` without any jQuery.
- `.prev().parent()` - the `prev` is absolutely unnecessary, all siblings do have the same parent node.
- `.prev(".payWeek")` - seems like you want to use [`.prevAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/) instead.
- `.next('input')` - you don't want to find the next sibling, but a descendant. Use [`.children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) or [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- `.prop('checked')` - while appropriate for checkboxes, you have number inputs here and need to set their `value`, via [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

So change it to

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '.fasCheck', function() {
        if (this.checked) {
            $(this)
              .parent()
              .prevAll(".payWeek")
              .find('input')
              .val('0');
        }
    });     
});
```

Comment: why don't you add proper answer

Answer (score 1):

From the clicked checkbox, find the closest `payWeek`, then select all previous `payWeeks`, and find all inputs within those `payWeeks` and set the value to zero :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '.fasCheck', function(){
        if ( this.checked ) {
            $(this).closest('.payWeek')
                   .prevAll('.payWeek')
                   .find('input')
                   .val('0');
        } else {

        }
    });     
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on('click', '.fasCheck', function(){

    var $this = $(this),
        $parent = $(this).parents('.returns').eq(0),
        $inputs = $parent.find('input');

    if ($this.prop("checked")){
        $inputs.val('0');
    } 
});
```